# Does DocumentCollection.stampAllMulti exist in XPages java?

Tags: java, xpages

Does anyone know why there is no such method in Java, only in LotusScript? I can only see StampAll, so it's not just a name change.

A serious omission if you ask me...

Comment: Too broad?? Ah, it's the phrase "anoyone know why"? Goodness, really? In any case, both answers prove that they understood the question, and the 2nd answer nailed it. Too bad too broad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear so. There is no `stampAllMulti()` for any `lotus.domino` classes we extend in ODA. (I think I've seen errors if we don't include a method that exist in the core API.) But we have added (for both `DocumentCollection` and `ViewEntryCollection`) a method `stampAll(Map<String, Object>)`.

It's worth bearing in mind that the Java API pre-dates XPages and is controlled by a different team within IBM.

I would recommend raising a PMR and including a test that uses a Java agent (to ensure it bypasses the XPages team and gets directly to the Java API team), and also include a LotusScript agent showing standard behaviour for that language.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does, since 8.5. Here is a quote from the help:

### Quote

Replaces the values of specified items in all documents in a document collection.

Defined in

DocumentCollection

Syntax
public void stampAllMulti(Document document)
    throws NotesException

Parameters
Document document
The document contains multiple items, each with values appropriate for the item type.

### End Quote

I don't think I've used it however.

Comment: No it doesn't, at least not in our XPages Designer R 9.0.1, for I get Java compilation errors. I know the Help says otherwise, so one might be inclined to think it's there... Thanks, and feel free to try it in XPages. PS I didn't try in SSJS.

Comment: I forgot to add: I could be mistaken of course...